# How to correctly append many divs using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have such long html code, for alert when you have old browser:

```
<div class="ie-message" style="display: block; ">
      <div class="alert error">
        <h2>
          Sorry, your web-browser is outdated
        </h2>
        <p>
          We recommend you install new version of web-browser
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="browsers-list">
        <div class="browser-button chrome">
          <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button firefox">
          <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/">Mozilla Firefox</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button opera">
          <a href="http://www.opera.com/download/">Opera</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button safari">
          <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Apple Safari</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button ie">
          <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Internet-explorer/default.aspx">Internet Explorer</a>
        </div>
      </div><div class=?"ie-message" style=?"display:? block;? ">?<div class="ie-message" style="display: block; ">
      <div class="alert error">
        <h2>
          Sorry, your web-browser is outdated
        </h2>
        <p>
          We recommend you install new version of web-browser
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="browsers-list">
        <div class="browser-button chrome">
          <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button firefox">
          <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/">Mozilla Firefox</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button opera">
          <a href="http://www.opera.com/download/">Opera</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button safari">
          <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Apple Safari</a>
        </div>
        <div class="browser-button ie">
          <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Internet-explorer/default.aspx">Internet Explorer</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

How can I append it using jquery? when i write this all in one string I get what i need

```
$('body').append('<div class="ie-message" style="display: block; "><div class="alert error"><h2>Sorry, your web-browser is outdated</h2><p>We recommend you install new version of web-browser</p></div><div class="browsers-list"><div class="browser-button chrome"><a href="http://www.google.com/chrome">Google Chrome</a></div><div class="browser-button firefox"><a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/">Mozilla Firefox</a></div><div class="browser-button opera"><a href="http://www.opera.com/download/">Opera</a></div><div class="browser-button safari"><a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Apple Safari</a></div><div class="browser-button ie"><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Internet-explorer/default.aspx">Internet Explorer</a></div></div><div class="close-text">close</div></div>');
```

, but how to make that every html tag will be on new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append each element as you create it, and set attributes using `.attr()`
e.g.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
$(div).attr("class", "ie-message");
$.('body').append(div);

var subDiv = document.createElement("div");
$(subDiv).attr("class", "browser-list");
$.(div).append(subDiv);
```

etc.

although if setting class attributes you should use `.addClass()` and when setting css attributes you are best of using `.css()` e.g.

```
$(div).addClass("ie-message");
```

and

```
$(div).css("display", block");
```

Answer (score 5):

To use newline characters in JavaScript strings, you could use what the spec refers to as a `LineContinuation`. Just prepend every new line with a `\` character:

```
$('body').append('\
  <div>\
    <p>foo</p>\
  </div>\
');
```

This is a way to spread a string over multiple lines (for easier code editing, for example), without the string actually including any new line characters.

This is the fastest way to do what you want.

However, JSLint advises against this. (I personally don’t care.)

You could use string concatenation instead:

```
$('body').append('<div>' +
  '  <p>foo</p>' +
  '</div>');
```

Or you could even use `Array#join`, writing each array item on a new line:

```
$('body').append([
  '<div>',
  '  <p>foo</p>',
  '</div>'
].join(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like this

```
jQuery('#selector').append('<div class="ie-message" style="display: block;">' +
   '<div class="alert-error">' +
      '<h2>' +
         …
      '</h2>' +
   '</div>' +
'</div>');
```

Honestly though, I think you're better off having the message already there but hidden. Then you only make it visible instead of actually appending the message.

Answer (score 0):

How about you make this text the default (static) content of the page and then overwrite it with the real content if the browser is good enough?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the HTML into a separate page and call it via AJAX. Like this:

```
if (oldBrowser) {
    $(".ie-message").load("/path/to.html").show();
}
```

Obviously, `oldBrowser` is a variable which is the result of browser sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` in your strings when using javascript to create a newline on the `\n`. If you want to create a newline in the viewed page, then use a `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

just make this div hidden.

```
<div class="ie-message" style="display: hidden; ">
```

andd when you wanna alert call this:

```
  $(".ie-message").dialog({modal:true});
```